# How to set width of TouchableWithoutFeedback depends on Text in react-native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I use `TouchableWithoutFeedback` to do a Button, but the width of the button is full width of screen.

[image: This is my button]

I expect this button:

[image: depends on the text]

And these are my styles:

```
btnDependText: {
    backgroundColor: '#29b088',
}
```

Comment: `<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => handlePress()} >
        <View
          style={[
            styles.btn,
            (type === 'dependOnText' ? styles.btnDependText : styles.btnDependWidth)
          ]}
        >
          <Text style={(type === 'dependOnText') ? styles.btnLabelText : styles.btnLabelWidth} >
            {label}
          </Text>
        </View></TouchableWithoutFeedback>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most likely to do with the container rather than the button itself, check out this snack for example: https://snack.expo.io/@jamie/so-answer.

**Component markup**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={styles.button} onPress={() => console.warn('pressed!')}>
          <View style={styles.buttonInner}>
            <Text>Button</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Styles**

If you style the container with:

```
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
```

Then you should get the look that you're after.

However if you remove the `alignItems: center` then you'll see that the button goes full-width.

Hope that helps!